# Calculate bounding box coordinates of a selected polygon with QGIS

Tags: qgis, extents

I just manually (and somewhat inaccurately I'm sure) retrieved the bounding box coordinates for a county polygon, which is a selection from a larger layer of county shapes. I'd like to be able to use a QGIS plugin or other function to calculate this quickly and not-by-hand. This is almost certainly possible but I couldn't find anything with a Google search

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following little Python function will output the bounding box coordinates of the currently active feature:

```py
def printBB():
    feature = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()[0]
    print feature.geometry().boundingBox().toString()
```

To define the function, open the Python console from the Plugins menu, copy and paste the three lines into the console, and press enter. Then you can call the function by typing `printBB()` and pressing enter while the desired feature is selected.

Edit: **For newer Python versions** (Python 3.x) use this (`print()` with brackets):

```
def printBB():
    feature = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()[0]
    print(feature.geometry().boundingBox().toString())
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to run this script: 

`File "<input>", line 4
    printBB()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @cbunn make sure you have the layer selected in the layers / table of contents - it's very sensitive to this!

Comment: thanks for the help.  I was also forgetting to press enter to fully define the function printBB() before calling it.

Comment: I had to use  print(feature.geometry().boundingBox().toString()) for line 3.

Comment: I got the following error for this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)

And many others.

Answer (score 20):

QGIS can do it via Polygon from Layer Extent

**Vector - Research tools - Polygon From Layer Extent**

Will produce a new shapefile with attributes like XMIN XMAX YMIN YMAX AREA WIDTH HEIGHT

Comment: You have to check `Use only selected obects` and `calculate for every object` to get the desired result.

Comment: hmm that didn't work for me, the outputted shapefile was blank essentially

Comment: You only want to check 'Use only selected objects' if you have objects selected. I left both those fields unchecked and achieved a fine result.

Answer (score 6):

If you need many polygon's bounding boxes, on the left hand side,

- Right click on your layer
- Click "Export"
- Click "Save Feature As"

The in the dialog that pops up,

- Set "Format" to "GeoJSON"
- Under the "Layer Options" set **WRITE_BBOX** to **YES**

Now when you export look inside the file for "bbox" (should be before the feature declaration), like this:

```
..., "bbox": [ -70.062408006999874, 12.417669989000046, -69.876820441999939, 12.632147528000104 ], "geometry": ...
```

Comment: I found  a special case bug with export - when your feature crosses the "prime antimeridian" (180 deg longitude), the bounding box values seem wrong.  It seems the bounding box coordinates are the max and min coordinates over all the vertices.  If the polygon crosses the antimeridian, the min longitude will be close to -180 and the max longitude close to 180.  But the most eastward and westward vertices will be different from the min and max longitudes.  I believe this represents a bug, but I will need to research further.  I encountered this problem working with the U.S. state of Alaska.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this using PyShp plugin in Python.. Its a lot simpler...

```
import shapefile

sf = shapefile.Reader("Path to shapefile...") 
shapes = sf.shapes() 
bbox = shapes[0].bbox # Retrieves the bounding box of the first shape

print bbox # Will print the bounding box coordinates
```

More information on PyShp and other functionalities can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp).

Answer (score 1):

For quick acces, an option is to keep bbox coordinates in the attribute table.

Toogle edit mode

Launch *Field calculator*

Set create new field, set *name (e.g xmin), type (decimal), length, (precision)*

Expression: **x_min( $geometry)**

You will get a new field in the attribute table with LEFT coordinate.

Repeat this for RIGHT, BOTTOM, TOP with expressions:

**x_max($geometry)**

**y_min($geometry)**

**y_max($geometry)**

Example of the result
[image]

You can then set [AutoFields plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) to automatically update these fields when feature is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to generate a field I could import as a list elsewhere.

1. Install QGIS plugin FieldPyculator
2. Toggle editing of layer
3. Create new column in attribute table as string e.g. bbox (save edits)
4. Open FieldPyculator
5. Set Update Field to bbox
6. In Field expression type something like:

   `bb =  $geom.boundingBox().toString()`

   `bb = bb.replace(' ','')`

   `bb = bb.replace(':',',')`

   `value = bb`
7. Run
8. Turn off editing and save layer