# Get Bounding Box of Map Extent in Stand Alone Application

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, extents

I basically have the same question as: 
[How to quickly calculate bounding box coordinates of a selected polygon with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79248/how-to-quickly-calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-of-a-selected-polygon-with-qgi). 
However I am building a stand alone application in python and so do not have the iFace class. I can get to the extent class easily enough with  :

```
box = layer2.extent()
OR box = self.map_canvas.extent()
```

Which gives me an object that claims it is an extent, but how do I get the coordinates out?

Comment: I know it must be simple, thanks! I'm confused though, ".xMinimum" didn't show up as an intellisense option?  p.s. if you move this to an answer i can close the question.

Comment: Most welcome! Not sure about it popping up as an option for a stand-alone application (haven't made one myself yet) but you could always ask it as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following to get the coordinates of your extent:

```
xmin = layer2.extent().xMinimum()
xmax = layer2.extent().xMaximum()
ymin = layer2.extent().yMinimum()
ymax = layer2.extent().yMaximum()
```