# Export MBRs from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, bbox

What would be the Overpass query to export minimum bounding rectangles (MBR) of cities/provinces/countries from OpenStreetMap?

Comment: Are you looking for exporting administrative boundaries from osm? AFAIK MBR does not exist as such in osm. Please edit your question

Comment: @juminet no I'm looking for actual bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mmd2 says, you can use `out bb;` (see the API documentation [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Control_output_format_.28print.2C_out.29) and discussion on this action [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Actions) (was `print` - now `out`).  BB in this context means Bounding Box (aka MBR).

However, if you have already downloaded the administrative boundaries of these features, you can use your favorite GIS to derive/show their BBoxes e.g. [ST_Envelope](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) in PostGIS.  For QGIS do a search on this forum and there are plenty of related posts like [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79248/how-to-quickly-calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-of-a-selected-polygon-with-qgi).