# Getting bounding box of polygon

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, extents, pyqgis-3

I'm having difficulties to get the bounding box of a polygon. My code is the following:

```py
def getBoundingBox(self):
    boundingBox = []
    polygon = self.getVectorLayer()
    vertices = polygon.geometry().asPolygon()

    xmax = vertices[0].x()
    xmin = vertices[0].x()
    ymax = vertices[0].y()
    ymin = vertices[0].y()

    for vertice in vertices:
        if vertice.x() > xmax:
            xmax = vertice.x()
        if vertice.x() < xmin:
            xmin = vertice.x()
        if vertice.y() > ymax:
            ymax = vertice.y()
        if vertice.y() < ymin:
            ymin = vertice.y()

    boundingBox.append(xmax)
    boundingBox.append(xmin)
    boundingBox.append(ymax)
    boundingBox.append(ymin)

    return boundingBox
```

The error message I get is

> AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'geometry'

The function `self.getVectorLayer()` works perfectly fine for other tools I wrote, thus this shouldn't be the problem. With the line `xmax = vertices[0].x()` 
I wanted to get the first vertice in the polygon, which probalby doesn't work that way, but it seems the problem starts even earlier.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/79248/49538

Comment: if you check "layer = iface.activeLayer()", then dir(layer) you'll see there's no attribute "geometry", maybe you can use "layer.extent()" which returns the coordinates as well. Maybe you are looking for "layer.getFeature().geometry()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing a feature with a vector layer.

A feature is a row on a vector layer that may contain attributes and geometry.
A vector layer is a set of features that represent "the same kind of data", like a set of roads.

(Im being really simplistic with this explanation, please look more into it)

Now, assuming that you want the bounding box of all features in a vector layer, select all the features in the vector layer and use the method [boundingBoxOfSelected()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a375966878cfd0a8ff7fcad0f0550d820)

```py
def getBoundingBox(self):
    layer = self.getVectorLayer()
    layer.selectAll()
    return layer.boundingBoxOfSelected()
```

Comment: this looks super useful. Thank you for that. Just one more question to make sure I got it right. If I wright in another function something like 

bbox = self.getBoundingBox()

and then I want the xMax value of my bounding box I can acces it with bbox.xMax because bbox is an object that includes the four double variables xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax. 

Am I right

Comment: Almost right, the actual attribute to access would be bbox.xMaximum(). As described in the docs for [QgsRectangle](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRectangle.html#a7fe11d0cd4fb7146dca5516c3eb03347) (which is the class of the object returned by the boundingBoxOfSelected method)